# Why are the textbox not editable and shows the lock icon in packing slip journal of dynamics ax 2012?

Tags: dynamic-programming, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

The issue that I've been trying to solve is that sometimes the text boxes are grayed out and it shows the lock icon, when supposedly these text boxes are not grayed out and it shows some information about the shipment tracking.

This issue is intermittent.

What could be the cause of this issue and how do we solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add more detail about your specific issue?

Comment: When I open the packing slip journal of a particular sales order, and go to Order tracking tab, I get this issue. see screencast: http://screencast.com/t/pJED9DDekcf9

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens after a modification of objects, when the X++ code of the form and the equivalent CIL code doesn't match, or when the database is not properly synchronized with underlaying CIL code.

Try runing a sync of the database and an incremental CIL generation and the checkbox will run properly.